# How Subscribe to multiple async http calls and apply filter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to subscribe to two http calls, and make sure don't fail after that , I want to apply a filter on the arrays that I  get in const array.

```
  const result =[]
    this.fncservice.obs.subscribe((response)=>this.fncservice.maptofncbyetat(response,this.fnc,"en cours"));       
 

 this.analysefncservice.obs.subscribe((response)=>this.analysefncservice.maptoplanactionbyetat(response,this.analysefncs,"en cours"));
   // the filter 
 this.fnc.forEach((filter) => {
          if (
            !this.analysefncs
              .filter((condition) => condition.n_fnc == filter.n_fnc)
              .some((nc) => nc.etat != "act")
          ) {
            console.log("succes" , filter.n_fnc)

            result.push(filter.n_fnc);
          }
        });
      });
```

the problem that I get null in  result . How to use forkjoin or switchmap to asynch my service call and apply the filter when the calls is end ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have an extra set of `});` somehow -  I'm surprised this compiles for you.

Answer (score 1):

As you do, you don't wait for the subscribe to complete to apply the filter.

Using `forkJoin`, as you say, is a good option to wait for the two subscribe to be done.

You can do it like this

```
const result =[]

forkJoin([
  this.fncservice.obs,
  this.analysefncservice.obs
]).subscribe((result) => {
  this.fncservice.maptofncbyetat(result[0],this.fnc,"en cours")
  this.analysefncservice.maptoplanactionbyetat(result[1],this.analysefncs,"en cours")
  this.fnc.forEach((filter) => {
    if (
      !this.analysefncs
      .filter((condition) => condition.n_fnc == filter.n_fnc)
      .some((nc) => nc.etat != "act")
    ) {
      console.log("succes" , filter.n_fnc)
      result.push(filter.n_fnc);
    }
  });
},(error) => {
  // error message
})
```

Because of

> forkJoin : Accepts an Array of ObservableInput or a dictionary Object of ObservableInput and returns an Observable that emits either an array of values in the exact same order as the passed array, or a dictionary of values in the same shape as the passed dictionary.

I first suppose that `this.fncservice.obs` and `this.analysefncservice.obs` are both `Observable`.

And then, as you can see, in the subscribe of the `forkJoin`, I send `result[0]` and `result[1]` as you did in each subscribe before.

Comment: Thank  u @Alexis for ur reply but I still have the same prblm as before the filter didn"t get applied

Comment: @HamzaNouri Then your problem isn't waiting for the service calls. Maybe your filter or one of your other function calls is broken. We can't help you with that at we can't see those.

Comment: @HamzaNouri, as @Mrk Sef told, the problem might be in your filter or in your arrays `analysefncs` or `fnc` :/